# Нужна ли запятая в сложносочиненном предложении, если оба подлежащих указывают на один субъект?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Нужна ли запятая в подобном предложении:

> Повсюду снуют какие-то люди(,) и они невеселы.

Вроде бы сложносочиненное предложение, но оба подлежащих указывают на один субъект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это ССП, запятая ставится.

При определении грамматической основы предложений следует учитывать, что один субъект может быть выражен двумя грамматическими подлежащими, что соответствует двум простым предложениям в составе ССП.

Comment: а если это одно и то же слово? К примеру "они дружны, и они неразлучны".

Comment: Это не имеет значения. В данном случае речь идет об отличии ССП от простого предложения с однородными членами, например: Они дружны и неразлучны. Эти варианты во всем различны: разная грамматическая основа, разная структура, разная интонация. Может быть, вы путаете эту тему с другой: отсутствие запятой в ССП при наличии общего члена, например: "Губы У КАТИ не улыбались и глаза выражали недоумение".